# Common route resolver in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, normalize

I am using route resolver in angularjs,for user will be redirect to login if user is not logged in as follows,

```
 $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/main/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController',
            resolve: {
                login: function ($rootScope, $location) {
                    if (!$rootScope.currentUser) {
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Here I want use this login function in many other routes,So i can copy paste same resolve function to every where as follows,

```
.when('/items', {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/item/list.html',
            controller: 'itemController',
            resolve: {
                login: function ($rootScope, $location) {
                    if (!$rootScope.currentUser) {
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

It is working fine,my question is,is there any way to avoid this duplication of codes or is there any other better method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set up a github repository yesterday which is a starting point for a web app and contains this feature [here](https://github.com/daniel7912/node-passport-sequelize-angular-stack)

If you look in `public/app/app-routes.js` you will see I have added resolve functions as variables, then you can simply do this rather than writing a whole function each time:

Function

```
var checkLoggedIn = function($q, $timeout, $http, $window, $location, $rootScope) {
        // Initialize a new promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // Make an AJAX call to check if the user is logged in
        $http.get('/loggedin').success(function(user) {

            // Authenticated
            if (user !== '0') {
                $rootScope.loggedInUser = user;
                $window.sessionStorage['loggedInUser'] = JSON.stringify(user);
                deferred.resolve();
            }

            // Not Authenticated
            else {
                $window.sessionStorage['loggedInUser'] = null;
                $rootScope.loggedInUser = null;
                deferred.reject();
                $location.url('/login');
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
    checkLoggedIn.$inject = ["$q", "$timeout", "$http", "$window", "$location", "$rootScope"];
```

Route

```
.when('/profile', {
            title: 'Profile',
            templateUrl: '/app/templates/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController',
            resolve: {
                loggedIn: checkLoggedIn
            }
        })
```

Should be easily adaptable for your app. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for answer, I will check and come back soon :)